# Get label of selected AutoHotKey GUI menu item

Tags: menu, autohotkey

I want to create small menu for special characters, directly inserting selected character into text.

For example, this small popup menu opens on <kbd>F9</kbd> as a context menu:

```
Menu, Ctx1, Add, €, InsertMenuLabel
Menu, Ctx1, Add, ¥, InsertMenuLabel
Menu, Ctx1, Add, ¢, InsertMenuLabel
Menu, Ctx1, Add, £, InsertMenuLabel

F9:
    Menu, Ctx1, Show, %A_GuiX%, %A_GuiY%
    Return
```

How do simply retrieve label of menu item which was selected? In the following code, how can I carry menu item label into `%MenuItemLabel%`?)

```
InsertMenuLabel:
    Send %MenuItemLabel%
    Return
```

I know this can be done using individual branch for each menu item (`InsertChar1` ... `InsertChar4`) but it is not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it:

```
InsertMenuLabel:
    Send %A_ThisMenuItem%
    Return
```